# Android Studio TCP client failed connecting to a GUI server

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio, tcp

**[UPDATED / ANSWERED]**

I am trying to make a connection between a android client application and a GUI java program using NetBeans on windows.

The server started and working fine but when i try to connect the client to it with the same port number it fails, and here are the codes :

The server on windows :

```
package server.test;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ServerThread extends Thread{
Server serverform;

ObjectInputStream OIS;  
ObjectOutputStream OUS;

ServerSocket serverSocket;

Socket socket;

public ServerThread(Server serverForm){
this.serverform = serverform;
     try{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1789);
    start();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(serverform, "Server started!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public void sendMessage(String msg){
    try{
        OUS.writeObject(msg.toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run(){
    while(true){
        try{
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            openReader();
           }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }
}

public void openReader(){
    try{
        OIS = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        OUS = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        MsgRecThread mrt = new MsgRecThread(serverform, OIS, OUS);

    }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class MsgRecThread extends Thread{
    Server serverform;
    ObjectInputStream OIS;  
    ObjectOutputStream OUS;

    public MsgRecThread(Server serverForm, ObjectInputStream OIS, ObjectOutputStream OUS){
        this.serverform = serverform;
        this.OIS = OIS;
        this.OUS = OUS;
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
        try{
           serverform.jTextArea1.append(OIS.readObject().toString() + "\n");
           }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    }

   }
}
```

And here is the client code on Android Studio :

**MainActivity.java**

```
01 : package com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3;
02 : 
03 : import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
04 : import android.os.Bundle;
05 : import android.view.View;
06 : import android.widget.Button;
07 : import android.widget.TextView;
08 : import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
09 : import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
10 : import java.net.Socket;
11 : 
12 : public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
13 : Socket socket;
14 : 
15 : ObjectInputStream OIS;
16 : ObjectOutputStream OUS;
17 : 
18 : @Override
19 : protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
20 : super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
21 : setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
22 : 
23 : Button sendBUT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBUT);
24 : Button stcBUT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stcBUT);
25 : 
26 : stcBUT.setOnClickListener(
27 :      new Button.OnClickListener(){
28 :            public void onClick(View v){
29 :                Button stcBUT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stcBUT);
30 :                try{
31 :                    socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1789);
                        operReader();
                        stcBUT.setText("Client connected!");
                        stcBUT.setEnabled(false);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        stcBUT.setText("Try again!");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
          }
    );

    sendBUT.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    try{
                        OUS.writeObject(R.id.editText);;
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}

private void operReader() {
    try{
        OUS = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        OIS = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        MsgRecThread mrt = new MsgRecThread(this, OUS, OIS);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class MsgRecThread extends Thread{
    MainActivity ma;
    ObjectOutputStream OUS;
    ObjectInputStream OIS;

    public MsgRecThread(MainActivity ma, ObjectOutputStream OUS, ObjectInputStream OIS){
        this.ma = ma;
        this.OIS = OIS;
        this.OUS = OUS;
        start();
    }
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                try{
                    TextView receivedMessages = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.receivedMessages);
                    receivedMessages.append(OIS.readObject().toString() + "\n");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is happening in the line :

```
socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1789);
```

And here is the logcat when i try to connect the client :

```
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:576)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:560)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4496)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18603)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:561)
08-28 16:38:23.343 16841-16841/com.mousa.alfhaily.client_test3 W/System.err:    ... 17 more
```

**UPDATE / ANSWER :**

I can't use the IP (127.0.0.1), because the client and the server is not on the same machine, i have to use the IP of the server which is my PC local IP address.

Comment: Which error? Please post the logcat.

Comment: Of course you cannot use 127.0.0.1 to connect. But then you also did not tell where your client is running on.

Comment: @greenapps. I am running the client app on a physical device with API: 19 Android 4.4 (Kitkat), and what IP should i use, and thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: The ip of the server device.